# How do i bind my ObservableCollection<T> object in my codebehind to my listbox... Silverlight WP7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

This is my codebehind

```
public ObservableCollection<BuddyConnectFriendService.FriendStructure>
    FriendList { get; set; } // I want to bind this to my listbox


public Friends() //this is constructor
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this; //I think this is what I'm doing is right....:)
    }


<ListBox Height="523" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,6,0,0" Name="friendListBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="450">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Name="friendListboxDataItemStackPanel" Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock Name="friendUsername" FontSize="28" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

How do I bind my `FriendList` to the `ListBox`? `FriendList` has a property of `user.UserName` which I want to display it in the TextBlock "friendUsername".

Answer (score 4):

I'd change the constructor like this:

```
public Friends() //this is constructor
{
     InitializeComponent();         
     this.DataContext = this.FriendList; 
}
```

Use a DataTemplate like this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                ...
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding user.UserName}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: This is a good answer as it stands, when adding further advice thought just edit the existing answer rather than adding a comment on your own answer. Use comments to reply to comments made by others. (Precede the comment with @nameOfCommenterBeingRepliedto).

Answer (score 0):

Erno's answer is fine and valid. There is another way to get it to your using your method.

If you give you Page/UserControl a name (i.e. in the root element, give it a Name="MyPage" attribute).

Then you can do:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyPage.FriendList}">
```

which should work.

However, I would place your FriendList property into a ViewModel and use that view model as the `DataContext` of your Page/UserControl